# How to use flexdashboard if I'm importing an excel file?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I´m new using dashboards in Rstudio. I want to use the flexdashboard library but I'm having some problems trying to use it with an excel I want to import. This is my code:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(flexdashboard)
library(readxl)

Modelo <- read_excel("Modelo.xlsx")
dfdata <- data.frame(Modelo)
```

*** Graph (1)

```{r}
plot_ly(dfdata, x=~mexico, y=~usa, z=~germany) %>%
  add_markers(color=~germany)
```
````

The error shows that the path doesn´t exist. Is there a way to use my excel in this library? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the error is about the path not existing, then you need to make sure that your excel file is located in the same folder as your working directory.
To know your working directory, you can use this command:
`getwd()`
Make sure your file is placed in that folder and you will get rid of the error.

Comment: you can also used setwd() to set the working directory to something that is meaning for your project